# Rest Assured Trying to Post Multiple Files Formats But Receive 415 Response Code

Tags: java, post, multipartform-data, rest-assured

I'm trying to post several files, the API endpoint accept a file and json File, but I Receive a 415 Response Code

```
 @Test(enabled = true)
public void testResp(){
    RestAssured.given()
            .baseUri("http://localhost")
            .port(8082)
            .basePath("/documents/")
            .header(new Header("content-type", "multipart+/form-data"))
            .multiPart(new MultiPartSpecBuilder(directoryFiles)
                    .fileName("file.txt")
                    .controlName("file")
                    .mimeType("text/plain")
                    .build())
            .multiPart(new MultiPartSpecBuilder(directoryFiles)
                    .fileName("metadata-txt.json")
                    .controlName("metadata")
                    .mimeType("application/json")
                    .build())
            .when()
            .post("documents/")
            .then()
            .log()
            .all();

}
```

Log

HTTP/1.1 405
Allow: GET
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 31 Jul 2020 16:11:55 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive

{
"timestamp": "2020-07-31T16:11:55.657+00:00",
"status": 405,
"error": "Method Not Allowed",
"message": "",
"path": "/docmgmt/documents/documents/"
}

Now I have a Different Error,

Comment: 415 is `Unsupported Media Type`, Add a `.log().all()` after `given()` and check the logs for the content type, also post the logs here and we'll take a look

Comment: Please check a modification below

Comment: The details are still unclear, how did you get 415 first and 405 now ? Adding the changes I suggested is not going to make any difference functionally